# Why is Fn derived from FnMut (which is derived from FnOnce)?

Tags: rust, traits

If you look in the [official Rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), you see that the trait `Fn` is derived from `FnMut`, or, to implement `Fn`, you have to implement `FnMut` (and after that `FnOnce` since `FnMut` also derives from it).

Why is that so? I simply can't comprehend that. Is it because you can call every `Fn` as a `FnOnce` or `FnMut`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best reference for this is the excellent [Finding Closure in Rust](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/finding-closure-in-rust/) blog post. I'll quote the salient part:

> There’s three traits, and so seven non-empty sets of traits that could possibly be implemented… but there’s actually only three interesting configurations:
>
> - `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`,
> - `FnMut` and `FnOnce`,
> - only `FnOnce`.
>
> Why? Well, the three closure traits are actually three nested sets: every closure that implements `Fn` can also implement `FnMut` (if `&self works`, `&mut self` also works; proof: `&*self`), and similarly every closure implementing `FnMut` can also implement `FnOnce`. This hierarchy is enforced at the type level

Comment: I just decided to use `IndexMut` instead of `FnMut` for my task, however, I think I spotted an error? Cause, for functions, there's (`FnOnce`), (`FnOnce`, `FnMut`), (`FnOnce`, `FnMut`, `Fn`). Alright, understood. But for the `Index`es it is: (`Index`), (`Index`, `IndexMut`). That's the other way around and a mistake I think, since, when I implement the mutable version, I have to have the immutable version too, which wont work... (Should I open a new question for that or does this comment suffice?)

Comment: @Kapichu it sounds like a different question to me. Specifically because I want to ask you what you mean by "which won't work". I bet that warrants a code snippet, which means it's probably another question. More questions are good - finer grained search results for the future people.

Comment: Ok I'll do it, this answer to this question helped me then! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a function need FnMut as input, but your closure only implement Fn.
Your closure can not be the input of the function. It is not flexible.

> every closure that implements Fn can also implement FnMut

The compiler auto implement FnMut and FnOnce for closure which can implement Fn. So that, the closure can be use of functions who's input is Fn or FnMut or FnOnce.