# Is it possible to avoid a pointless definition of `FnOnce`?

Tags: rust, overloading

In trying to experiment with overloading the call syntax, I introduced a simple cache that can cache the result of an expensive computation. I am a bit confused about the use of a piece of the syntax. I'll introduce the code step by step before the question.

The cache is intended to be used like this:

```
fn fib(x: i32) -> i32 {
    if x < 2 { x } else { fib(x-1) + fib(x-2) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cfib = Cache::new(fib);

    // Loop that repeats computation and extracts it from the cache
    // the second time.
    for x in 1..200 {
        let val = 5 * x % 40;
        println!("fibc({}) = {}", val, cfib(val));
    }
}
```

We first have the preamble to enable features that are not yet in stable:

```
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
```

We introduce the cache as a structure with a `HashMap` and a function to compute new values.

```
struct Cache<T, R> {
    cache: HashMap<T, R>,
    func: fn(T) -> R,
}

impl<T, R> Cache<T, R>
    where T: Eq + Hash + Copy,
          R: Copy
{
    fn new(func: fn(T) -> R) -> Cache<T, R> {
        Cache { cache: HashMap::new(), func: func }
    }

    fn compute(&mut self, x: T) -> R {
        let func = self.func;
        let do_insert = || (func)(x);
        *self.cache.entry(x).or_insert_with(do_insert)
    }
}
```

I create an implementation of the `FnMut` trait since the cache needs to be mutable.

```
impl<T, R> FnMut<(T,)> for Cache<T, R>
    where T: Eq + Hash + Copy,
          R: Copy
{
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (T,))
        -> Self::Output
    {
        let (arg,) = args;
        self.compute(arg)
    }
}
```

Even though I find the syntax `FnMut<(T,)>` quite strange, this is fine and safe and conveys the intentions quite clear. Since I need to define the return type of the function, I would like to write the beginning as:

```
impl<T, R> FnMut<(T,), Output=R> for Cache<T, R>
    where T: Eq + Hash + Copy,
          R: Copy
{}
```

But that fails with an error:

```
error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
  --> src/main.rs:55:24
   |
55 | impl<T, R> FnMut<(T,), Output=R> for Cache<T, R>
   |                        ^^^^^^^^ associate type not allowed here
```

I had to implement `FnOnce` like this:

```
impl<T, R> FnOnce<(T,)> for Cache<T,R>
    where T: Eq + Hash + Copy,
          R: Copy
{
    type Output = R;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _arg: (T,))
        -> Self::Output
    {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Which is kind of pointless since `call_once` will never be called, and from [Associated Types](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html) it seems like this should be possible. However, it fails with an error that associated types are not allowed there.

The [Rust Compiler Error Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html) mentions the syntax `Fn(T) -> R` and also says that `Fn<(T,), Output=U>` should work, but I cannot make it work even though I am using nightly Rust compiler.

Since it is desirable to catch as many errors as possible at compile time it would be good to avoid creating the "unimplemented" function in `FnOnce` since that will fail at runtime rather than compile time.

Is it possible to implement only `FnMut` and provide the return type of the function in some manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which is kind of pointless since `call_once` will never be called

That's not up to you to decide; that's up to the *caller*. They may decide to call the cache in a `FnOnce` context.

The good news is that there's a perfectly reasonable implementation of `FnOnce` — just delegate to the `FnMut` implementation:

```
impl<T, R> FnOnce<(T,)> for Cache<T,R>
    where T: Eq + Hash + Copy,
          R: Copy
{
    type Output = R;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, arg: (T,))
        -> Self::Output
    {
        self.call_mut(arg)
    }
}
```

This is what the compiler's automatic implementation of these traits does;  it also delegates `FnMut` to `Fn` if appropriate.

See also

- [Why is Fn derived from FnMut (which is derived from FnOnce)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31190851/155423)
- [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/155423)

Comment: Is the `extern "rust-call"` bit strictly necessary here?

Comment: @MatthieuM. yep. The trait defines an `extern "rust-call"` function, and the implementation has to match the trait definition. More broadly, `rust-call` is what tells the compiler that `arg` is really multiple arguments to the function and to do the transformation such that each tuple value is a separate argument. Presumably a single large tuple passed to a function behaves differently than many separate values at the hardware level.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It might be passed differently depending on the ABI indeed (for example, passing a single pointer instead of each element individually). I hadn't considered that, since in C++ it would be a variadic template call, which doesn't have this issue.